# GET dependents of a Github Actions via Github API

Tags: github, github-actions

I would like to get the dependents repositories of each GitHub Action in our organization which can be visible through the GitHub webpage( Insight > Dependencies > dependents).

I could not see any API for this provided by GitHub. How can I achieve this or if it is not possible how can I GET the all Github actions is using by each repository in organization via API?

[image: dependents]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible via api but you can using the scraping tool https://github.com/nvuillam/github-dependents-info